# Building and adding WolfSSL library to a new environment

Tags: ssl, build

I want to build the WolfSSL library in a non-standard environment, specifically a STM32F405 chip. The product i am trying to build the library for is a BitCrazy Crazyflie 2.0.

Having read the manual for WolfSSL, chapter 2.4 tells me that i need to keep the directory structure the same as in the downloaded package.

What i don't know is what parts of the download package does what and what parts of it is required for what functionality. My speculation is for basic WolfSSL functionality the parts of the download package i need are:

download_package/src

download_package/wolfssl

Other than these two directories i have no clue.

My needs are for DTLS 1.0 functionality and minimising the memory and storage footprint.

Answer (score 2):

wolfSSL offers a freely available porting guide for "building in a non-standard environment". The porting guide is located here:

https://wolfssl.com/wolfSSL/Docs-wolfssl-porting-guide.html

They also provide a tuning guide for removing features/custom tailoring a build here:

https://wolfssl.com/wolfSSL/Docs-wolfssl-tuning-guide.html

wolfSSL provides several DTLS examples located on github here:

https://github.com/kaleb-himes/wolfssl-examples/tree/master/dtls

It looks like if this line of code were to replaced:

```
wolfDTLSv1_2_client_method
```

with

```
wolfDTLSv1_client_method
```

In this section of https://github.com/kaleb-himes/wolfssl-examples/blob/master/dtls/client-dtls.c:

```
    if ( (ctx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(wolfDTLSv1_2_client_method())) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "wolfSSL_CTX_new error.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

You would get DTLS v1.0 instead of DTLS v1.2

Comment: UPDATE: wolfSSL added support for the CubeMX Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL). For those of you developing on STM32(F0, F1, F2, F3, F4, F7, L0, L1, or L4) if you are using the CubeMX code generator to produce your standard peripheral libraries then you could take advantage of the Harware Crypto support added in wolfSSLv3.10.0 release! See the defines in <wolfssl-root>/wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h WOLFSSL_STM32F2 and WOLFSSL_STM32F4 as a model if working on any of the other micros. Testing was done on the F2 and F4 so those are the only default options available right now

Comment: There's now a [tag:wolfSSL] tag. You can patrol it.

Comment: @jww Awesome! Thank you so much.